# iPhone OpenGL augmented reality

Tags: opengl-es, augmented-reality, camera-calibration

I am writing an iOS application (Xcode/swift) that capture real time images on the iPhone back camera. 
I have a transparent GLView and i want to display some objects in order to make augmented reality.
I know the field of view of this camera (about 60°). This value is transmit to GLKMatrix4MakePerspective.
But the sizes does not match with reality.
Does one OpenGL unit is one meter on the reality ? Is there a calibration to do ?

Comment: What other parameters are sent to MakePerspective?

Comment: Other parameters are aspect ratio of GLKView (width / height), nearz=0.1, farz=10000

Comment: I think providing an image of your current status would help so we get an idea of what your reality is. Also describe the model you try to render and its transforms.